# Linux iptable simple concentrator

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Hi All :) I have a simple question for who is strong in networking and iptables :)

I setup a test Apache server on 192.168.0.1, very simple, and want to concentrate all tcp/ip requests to it.. but unfortunately I cant find the working list options for iptables myself, something keeps not working..

So here what I need: I need to forward all eth0 frames TCP/IP requests directed to external IPs, instead towards the local 192.168.0.1:80 .

E.g. if my browser sends a HTTP request to external ip 1.2.3.4, the kernel has to "rewrite" the destination ip from 1.2.3.4 to 192.168.0.1:80, and send it to my Apache.

And of course the browser has to receive the answer back.

What is the list of rules? Thanks :)

Comment: That's total nonsense.. How will you reach the server or how should the server respond to clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything depends on where you want to apply that rule. On the machines generating the traffic? On the gateway? Somewhere else?

The solution for the machine making the request is:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp ! -d 192.168.0.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:80
```